# How to make the seconds hand move only forward on the clock?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I build an analog clock using react but have an issue with the seconds hand.
The seconds hand starts clockwise but once it reaches the 59 second mark it moves counter clockwise until it reaches the 1 second mark. After that it moves clockwise again. How can I make it continuously move clockwise?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './AnalogClock.css';

const AnalogClock = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const newTime = new Date();
      setTime(newTime);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  const getRotation = (unit, max) => {
    const value = time[`get${unit}`]();
    let rotation = (value * 360) / max;

    if (unit === 'Seconds') {
      const seconds = value + time.getMilliseconds() / 1000;
      rotation = (seconds * 6) % 360;

      if (rotation < 0) {
        rotation += 360;
      }
    }

    return {
      transform: `translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(${rotation}deg)`,
    };
  };

  const renderNumbers = () => {
    const numbers = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      const angle = (i * 30) * (Math.PI / 180);
      const numberStyle = {
        left: `calc(50% + ${Math.sin(angle) * 140}px)`,
        top: `calc(50% - ${Math.cos(angle) * 140}px)`,
      };
      numbers.push(
        <div key={i} className="number" style={numberStyle}>
          {i}
        </div>
      );
    }

    return numbers;
  };

  return (
    <div className="clock">
      {renderNumbers()}
      <div className="hour-hand" style={getRotation('Hours', 12)}></div>
      <div className="minute-hand" style={getRotation('Minutes', 60)}></div>
      <div
        className="second-hand"
        style={
          time.getSeconds() === 59
            ? { ...getRotation('Seconds', 60), transition: 'none' }
            : getRotation('Seconds', 60)
        }
      ></div>
      <div className="center-circle"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AnalogClock;
```

Not sure if the css will help but here it is.

```
.clock {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), -20px -20px 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .hour-hand,
  .minute-hand,
  .second-hand {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), -4px -4px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  
  .hour-hand {
    width: 8px;
    height: 90px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) translateX(-1px);
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  }
  
  .minute-hand {
    width: 6px;
    height: 120px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) translateX(-1px);
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  }
  
  .second-hand {
    width: 4px;
    height: 130px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) translateX(-1px);
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }
  
  .center-circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), -2px -2px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  .number {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 29px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying to inject js in css to achieve your goal I recommend that you use styled components to get some of the benefits of taking this to the next level and use js variables in css

The main limitation with your code is that you can't specify that the animation will continue forever so that is restarting the animation when it reach 360

This can be achieved with css keyframes and animation but without using styled components is difficult to pass some necessary params to keyframes and animation, like the initial degrees and the seconds that it will complete a loop

Here is more or less the approach with styled components

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';
import './styles.css';

const rotate = (degree) => keyframes`
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(${degree}deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%) rotate(${degree+360}deg);
  }
`

const ClockStick = styled.div`
  animation: ${(props) => rotate(props.degree)} ${(props) => props.seconds}s linear;
`

const App = () => {
  const [degrees, setDegrees] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setDegrees({
      hour: getRotation('Hours', 12),
      minute: getRotation('Minutes', 60),
      second: getRotation('Seconds', 60)
    })
  }, []);

  const getRotation = (unit, max) => {
    const time = new Date();
    const value = time[`get${unit}`]();
    const rotation = (value * 360) / max;
    return rotation;
  };

  const renderNumbers = () => {
    const numbers = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      const angle = (i * 30) * (Math.PI / 180);
      const numberStyle = {
        left: `calc(50% + ${Math.sin(angle) * 140}px)`,
        top: `calc(50% - ${Math.cos(angle) * 140}px)`,
      };
      numbers.push(
        <div key={i} className="number" style={numberStyle}>
          {i}
        </div>
      );
    }

    return numbers;
  };

  return (
    <div className="clock">
      {renderNumbers()}
      <ClockStick className="hour-hand" seconds={216000} degree={degrees.hour}></ClockStick>
      <ClockStick className="minute-hand" seconds={3600} degree={degrees.minute}></ClockStick>
      <ClockStick
        className="second-hand"
        seconds={60}
        degree={degrees.second}
      ></ClockStick>
      <div className="center-circle"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I removed some unnecessary logic and I will explain some things that I added

- Keyframes is essential to achieve this because is going to define how the animation is going to rotate (from initial rotation to initial rotation + 360) and also can be used with animation property that will be helpful in ClockStick
- ClockStick is the styled component that will receive the initial degrees and also the seconds that the animation will take to complete a cycle
- I declared only one state with the initial degrees that correspond to the specific time when the user runs the app
- Then I pass the seconds that each stick (ClockStick) will take to complete the cycle (216000 => for hours, 3600 => for minutes and 60 => for seconds)

Here is the result

https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-rgb-qn58t6

Some links related to the answer

- https://styled-components.com/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animations/Using_CSS_animations
- https://medium.com/@matt.readout/adding-css-animations-with-styled-components-6c191c23b6ba